# Confidence region of the predicted value in multiple regression that involves categorical predictors (plot)

Tags: multiple-regression, categorical-data, data-visualization

I'm wondering how can I plot the confidence region of the predicted value in multiple regression that involves categorical predictors, using either R/Stata. I've read about predicting using the main predictor while keeping other predictors at their mean value. In the case of multiple linear regression that has categorical predictors, what it means to use the mean value of the categorical variables?

If it's a simple linear regression, the confidence region around the fitted value looks like this (that of two models) - [image]

Comment: Categorical predictors don't have a mean, they take one of a set of possible values, eg, $x_{\text{cat}}\in\{a,b,c\}$. So we would plot one regression line/curve for each category.